# script – Photoshop image processing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to change over 60 web optimized images to fit their new containers. The current dimensions are 760 x 1024  or 1024x760.  is there an easy or simple solution to manipulating all of these images to a smaller size without changing the height/width ratio?

Answer (score 4):

Go to **File** -> **Scripts** -> **Image Processor...** it will open Image Processor panel just like this (this one is Mac OSX):

[image: Screenshot]

Now do this:

1) Select folder with your images (pre-sort images by portrait or landscape orientation).
2) Select where you want to save processed images.
3) Check "Resize to Fit" -> **enter height and width**. For example you want that your image will fit in 500x500px frame. Enter this size in textfields and your images will be scaled with aspect ratio (width or height will be 500px depending from ratio). Also choose format.
4) When you are ready to convert click "Run" button.
5) And that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not have the desired result because a horizontal item will be treated the same as a vertical item. You need to pre-sort your items into two folders before using this method. (not the end of the world and still faster than reprocessing manually). Also, some images might need to be PNG (transparency)

Comment: @horatio Yes, images need to be sorted. Horizontal in one folder ant vertical in another if images need to be sorted by width or height (if it is **required**). But I mean that it will convert with aspect ratio.

Comment: maybe add a step 1 e.g. "pre-sort images by portrait or landscape orientation "

Comment: this worked out perfectly. Thank you so much for your assistance and expertise. In

Comment: @Charles you're welcome. I'm glad that helped you.